# Authenticating in desktop app with Google Account

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, google-authentication

I'd like to access Firebase Storage or Google Cloud Storage from a Java desktop app using a user token. I can auth in the browser and get an access token and pass it to the desktop app to use, but that expires within an hour. I couldn't find a way to get a longer expiration or a refresh token, to generate new access tokens. Note - I'm not allowed to give the desktop app a client secret or service account creds, and setting up a server is also not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Since read and write access to Storage is restricted and only authenticated users can read or write data, to access Google Firebase Cloud Storage or Google Cloud Storage you need to connect to the storage as authenticated user. This can only be done with auth access token as you mentioned or through client library. There is no other option available. This is going to secure the connection between your app and the Google Cloud Storage services.

You need to import `com.google.cloud.storage` libraries to your Java desktop application and connect through the client to the storage. This will provide the necessary permissions to your desktop app to perform read and write operations to the storage. For more information about **Google Cloud Storage - Java** you can find in [Using Cloud Storage with Java](https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started/using-cloud-storage) documentation.

If this is not what you were looking for, please provide me with further information about your use case scenario so that is more clear of what you are trying to accomplish and why.